# how to validate the fields in xamarin form?

Tags: c#, validation, xamarin.forms, field

what's up?
How do the validations of the form in Xamarin, I for example want that when the user is registering and the button to register the field that does not complete in red, saying that this field is required, it is possible to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you could do all validations on the code behind or your viewmodel and create a custom renderer or a custom control to your entry or you can use some library like [PQXamarin](https://github.com/m0dawood/PQXamarin) or [Xamarin.Forms Unobtrusive FluentValidation Plugin](https://github.com/james-russo/XamarinForms-UnobtrusiveValidationPlugin) but you're still need to do all the validations

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're using `Entry` views for user inputs. Suppose you're checking the Username Entry named `UsernameEntry`, a good place to start is:

1. When the Registration button is tapped, do `UsernameEntry.TextColor = Color.Red`.
2. When the Registration button is tapped, perform a Null/Empty check using `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UsernameEntry.Text)`.
3. Use the `OnTextChanged` override to track user's text changes to the `Entry`.